# Python: better/simpler way of parsing string Enum values

Tags: python, parsing, enums

### Problem:

I'm parsing some config file and one field should be parsed to an Enum. Let's say there may be 3 possible values:

```
`foo`, `bar`, `baz`
```

And I want to parse them into the following enum's values:

```
class ConfigField(Enum):
    FOO = 'foo'
    BAR = 'bar'
    BAZ = 'baz'
```

### What have I tried so far:

I have written the following function to do that:

```
def parse_config_field(x: str) -> ConfigField:
    for key, val in ConfigField.__members__.items():
        if x == val.value:
            return val
    else:
        raise ValueError('invalid ConfigField: ' + str(x))
```

But I think this is ugly and too complicated for something so simple and straightforward.
I also considered just lowercasing enum field's names:

```
def parse_config_field2(x: str) -> ConfigField:
    value = ConfigField.__members__.get(x.lower(), None)
    if value is None:
        raise ValueError('invalid ConfigField: ' + str(x))
    else:
        return value
```

Which is slightly shorter, but still pretty ugly and what's worse, it creates direct dependence between config values (in some text config file) and `ConfigField` which I'm not comfortable with.

I just recently switched from python2 to python3 so I'm not 100% familiar with Enums and I'm hoping there may be a better way to do this.

### Question:

Is there a better way to do this? I'm looking for *simpler* (and perhaps more "built-in" / "pythonic") solution than my `parse_config_field` - perhaps something like:

```
value = ConfigField.get_by_value(cfg_string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for accessing by value: `ConfigField("foo")`, which gives `<ConfigField.FOO: 'foo'>`.

A `ValueError` will be raised for parsing using not existing values:

```
>>> ConfigField("not foo")
ValueError: 'not foo' is not a valid ConfigField
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 309, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 600, in __new__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 584, in __new__
    result = cls._missing_(value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\enum.py", line 613, in _missing_
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: 'not foo' is not a valid ConfigField
```